# unix - cut command (adding own delimiter)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Given a file with data like this (ie stores.dat file)

```
id               storeNo     type
2ttfgdhdfgh      1gfdkl-28   kgdl
9dhfdhfdfh       2t-33gdm    dgjkfndkgf
```

Desired output:

```
id               |storeNo     |type
2ttfgdhdfgh      |1gfdkl-28   |kgdl
9dhfdhfdfh       |2t-33gdm    |dgjkfndkgf
```

Would like to add a "|" delimiter between each of these 3 cut ranges:

```
cut -c1-18,19-30,31-40 stores.dat
```

What is the syntax to insert a delimiter between each cut?

BONUS pts (if you can provide the option to trim the values like so):

```
id|storeNo|type
2ttfgdhdfgh|1gfdkl-28|kgdl
9dhfdhfdfh|2t-33gdm|dgjkfndkgf\
```

**UPDATE (thanks to Mat's answer) I ended up with success on this solution - (it is a bit messy but SunOS with my bash version doesn't seem to support more elegant arithmetic)**

```
#!/bin/bash
unpack=""
filename="$1"
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    arg="$1"
    if [ "$arg" != "$filename" ]
    then
        firstcharpos=`echo $arg | awk -F"-" '{print $1}'`
        secondcharpos=`echo $arg | awk -F"-" '{print $2}'`
        compute=`(expr $firstcharpos - $secondcharpos)`
        compute=`(expr $compute \* -1 + 1)`
        unpack=$unpack"A"$compute
    fi
    shift
done
perl -ne 'print join("|",unpack("'$unpack'", $_)), "\n";' $filename
```

Usage: sh test.sh input_file 1-17 18-29 30-39

Comment: Do you require to use cut, this can be done with sed command easily

Comment: But if I didn't use cut, and say my input file were to change to have values at position 17,18,19 (2 fields run together without space) then how would the sed solution handle it?

Comment: Perhaps something like: cat stores.dat | sed 's/ \b/|/g'

Comment: Just use simple `tr` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not afraid of using perl, here's a one-liner:

```
$ perl -ne 'print join("|",unpack("A17A12A10", $_)), "\n";' input
```

The `unpack` call will extract one 17 char string, then a 12 char one, then a 10 char one from the input line, and return them in an array (stripping spaces). `join` adds the `|`s.

If you want the input columns to be in `x-y` format, without writing a "real" script, you could hack it like this (but it's ugly):

```
#!/bin/bash
unpack=""

while [ $# -gt 1 ] ; do
    arg=$(($1))
    shift
    unpack=$unpack"A"$((-1*$arg+1))
done

perl -ne 'print join("|",unpack("'$unpack'", $_)), "\n";' $1
```

Usage: `t.sh 1-17 18-29 30-39 input_file`.

Comment: This is great, is there an alternative that takes input of 1-18,19-30.etc rather than 17,12?

Comment: Added a suggestion for that, but at this point you should really consider writing a real perl script. BTW, either I messed up my input file, or your column spec is wrong - the first column is 1-17, not 1-18.

Answer (score 6):

Since you used `cut` in your example.
Assuming each field is separated with a tab:

```
$ cut  --output-delimiter='|' -f1-3 input
id|store|No
2ttfgdhdfgh|1gfdkl-28|kgdl
9dhfdhfdfh|2t-33gdm|dgjkfndkgf
```

if that is not the case, add the input-separator switch `-d`

Comment: This assumes tab separated fields not fixed length.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use awk:

```
awk '{print $1 "|" $2 "|" $3}'
```

Like some of the other suggestions, it assumes columns are whitespace separated, and doesn't care about the column numbers. If you have spaces in one of the fields, it won't work.

Comment: Why print the pipes when you can set the `OFS` to `|`. `awk -v OFS="|" '{print $1,$2,$3}' stores.dat`

Comment: This answer does not solve the asker's problem; columns are fixed length, not space-separated

Comment: Eagle eyes! But it goes with the disclaimer @ugoren has put up. :)

Comment: @ropata, this looks like an answer in itself, not a comment.

Comment: My complete answer is a [bit further down the page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25297938/148889), unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Better awk solution based on character position, not whitespace

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='17 12 10' -v OFS='|' '{ $1=$1 ""; print }' stores.dat | tr -d ' '

id|storeNo|type
2ttfgdhdfgh|1gfdkl-28|kgdl
9dhfdhfdfh|2t-33gdm|dgjkfndkgf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with `cut` as far as I am aware, but you can do it easily with `sed` as long as the values in each column never have *internal* spaces:

```
sed -e 's/  */|/g'
```

EDIT: If the file format is a true fixed-column format, and you don't want to use `perl` as shown by Mat, this *can* be done with `sed` but it's not pretty, because `sed` doesn't support numeric repetition quantifiers (`.{17}`), so you have to type out the right number of dots:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.................\)\(............\)\(..........\)$/\1|\2|\3/; s/  *|/|/g'
```

Comment: Problem if my input file were to change to have values at position 17,18,19 (2 fields run together without space). Also would be nice to handle the internal spaces.

Answer (score 0):

How about using just `tr` command.

```
tr -s " " "|" < stores.dat
```

From the `man` page:

```
-s      Squeeze multiple occurrences of the characters listed in the last
        operand (either string1 or string2) in the input into a single
        instance of the character.  This occurs after all deletion and
        translation is completed.
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat stores.dat 
id               storeNo     type
2ttfgdhdfgh      1gfdkl-28   kgdl
9dhfdhfdfh       2t-33gdm    dgjkfndkgf

[jaypal:~/Temp] tr -s " " "|" < stores.dat 
id|storeNo|type
2ttfgdhdfgh|1gfdkl-28|kgdl
9dhfdhfdfh|2t-33gdm|dgjkfndkgf
```

You can easily redirect this to a new file like this -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] tr -s " " "|" < stores.dat > new.stores.dat
```

#### Note: As Mat pointed out in the comments, this solution assumes each column is separated by one or more white-space and not separated by a fixed length.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use

```
cat stores.dat | tr -s ' ' '|'
```

Answer (score -1):

use 'sed' to search and replace parts of a file based on regular expressions

Replace whitespace with '|' from infile1

```
sed -e 's/[ \t\r]/|/g' infile1 > outfile3
```