# Insert output-delimiter with unix cut *-c*

Tags: unix, delimiter, cut

The documentation for `cut` (cf `info cut`) says:

> `--output-delimiter=OUTPUT_DELIM_STRING`
>
> ```
> With `-f`, output fields are separated by OUTPUT_DELIM_STRING.
>  The default with `-f` is to use the input delimiter.  When using
>  `-b` or `-c` to select ranges of byte or character offsets (as
>  opposed to ranges of fields), output OUTPUT_DELIM_STRING between
>  non-overlapping ranges of selected bytes.
> ```

My understanding is that therefore this:

```
 echo abcdefghi | cut --output-delimiter=',' -c 1-2,5-6
```

Should give `ab,ef`. But it prints `abef`...

How do I achieve `ab,ef`? Have I misunderstood the documentation?

Before closing as dupe, please note that:

- I am aware that I could use `awk` or `sed` or `perl` or `bash` or (..) (see [this similar question with an ugly accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630053/unix-cut-command-adding-own-delimiter)) but I am after a `cut` solution, especially since the documentation says it should work.
- I am using `-c` and not `-f`

Comment: What is your version? `cut (GNU coreutils) 8.22` produces the desired output.

Comment: cut (GNU coreutils) 5.97 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11

Comment: That is really old. Upgrade recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 8.22, the behavior is as expected:

```
$ echo abcdefghi | cut --output-delimiter=',' -c 1-2,5-6
ab,ef
$ cut --version
cut (GNU coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Given that you're using the 5.9 series, officially released around 2006, I think we can conclude this is a bug in that series. Given that you're on RedHat, your version likely has had security fixes back-ported, but not paper cut bugs like this one.

Solution would be to upgrade, or use an alternative tool as you've pointed out.